# How to have the url format like xyz.com/template.html/?token=&uid=/ using django rest_auth

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am making the program, whenever the user forgets his password, he get's an email after entering the email id. This thing is working. It is even sending the url in the mail and everything is working. But currently my url in the email is like this.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/reset/MTg/4z1-d4e4774f2d5b3cad07a9/

But I want my url to be in the format.

htttp://127.0.0.1:8000/account/reset/?uid=xyz&token=bdfjkdbfkjdbf.

This is just an example: I can change that account/reset to my template. That will be done. But what I want is it's format should be like this. It's just a rough idea. One of the most important thing, I want to use only django-rest-auth. I am not using anything else.

Comment: Can you add the view you are currently using for the reset?

Comment: @JPG I’m using the default rest_auth. My coworker knows how to do it. But he’s not telling me. As he’s a real pain in the ass. I tried everything. But nothings good.

Comment: We can't help if we don't see the view., Because it's the key part here

Comment: Another possible solution is, create another view from scratch.....

Comment: @JPG okay can you please tell me how to create it from scratch. I don't know how to do that. My views doesn't contain anything related to this.

Comment: SO is not a place for that. You should've tried something yourself and if you got any error or something ask a question here

Comment: @JPG Sir I know I am not doing right. I have made a chatbot all by myself. Everything is working. Just this last thing is left. So can you please help me out ? I don't know anything about this.